# HTML File Upload - Longer textfield for selected filepath?

Tags: html

Say I have a HTML page that looks like this: [image: "Välj Fil" means Upload File]

That was created with this code:

```
 <body>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />
</body>
```

Is there some way to make the textfield for the file path longer, so that I can read the entire path?

I've seen solutions such as [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), but it seems waaay to advanced for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `width` attribute stretches the field for me in Chrome and IE8.

```
<input type="file" style="width: 100%">
```

It doesn't work in FF4, though.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GZAEc/

Comment: Thanks. As you said doesn't work in FF4 but it's enough for me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

add the `size="x"` attribute to your input tag.

Comment: Didn't get this to work, I suppose this would make the field only as long as it needed to be? That'd be desireable, have you gotten this to work?

Comment: Yes. `<input type="file" size="50">` The size is measured in characters, not pixels, just like any other text field.